# Finding a specific index in a binary image in linear time?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, boolean, python-imaging-library

I've got a 640x480 binary image (0s and 255s). There is a single white blob in the image (nearly circular) and I want to find the centroid of the blob (it's always convex). Essentially, what we're dealing with is a 2D boolean matrix. I'd like the runtime to be linear or better if possible - is this possible?

Two lines of thought so far:

1. Make use of the `numpy.where()` function
2. Sum the values in each column and row, then find where the max value is based on those numbers... but is there a quick and efficient way to do this? This might just be a case of me being relatively new to python.

Comment: Have you seen [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) yet? Python bindings are available and since it is used in some heavy places, I'd hope it is reasonably optimized by now.

Comment: +1 for Opencv, for simple achievements like this one, you won't do better by yourself (easily ^^)

Comment: How accurate does the centroid detection need to be? And is the size of the blob known?

Comment: The centroid detection needs to be as accurate as possible, and the size is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will find the centroid of any shaped image. It will find it exactly for `rez = 1`. Increasing `rez`, increases the grid spacing, so can massively increase the speed of the search, at the obvious cost of the accuracy. If the size of the blob is known within bounds you could chain a low `rez` search, with a high `rez` search, thus finding the answer quickly and pricesely

```
import Image

def find_centroid_faster(im, rez):
    width, height = im.size
    XX, YY, count = 0, 0, 0
    for x in xrange(0, width, rez):
        for y in xrange(0, height, rez):
            if im.getpixel((x, y)) == 255:
                XX += x
                YY += y
                count += 1
    return XX/count, YY/count
```

for example, with the below image:

```
im = Image.open('blob.png')
print find_centroid(im, 1)
print find_centroid(im, 20)
#output:
(432, 191)
(430, 190)
```

Timing with `timeit` the first option (which is linear time, `O(n)`) has a run time of `1.7s`, and the second `0.005s`.

You can't do better than `O(n)` to find an exact answer, unless you have some constraints on size and shape. **But**, you can sacrifice accuracy for speed. The above code is `O(n/(rez ** 2))`, which can be a massive improvement. The accuracy of reported results is: `± rez / 2`, in each dimension.

**Update:**

`sega_sai` wrote a nice piece of `numpy` code (see post below) to find the centroid. I've modified it to take advantage of grid spacing, by using slicing. It operates in the same fashion as above:

```
def find_centroid_faster_numpy(im,rez):
        h, w = im.size
        arr = np.array(im)
        arr_rez = arr[::rez,::rez]
        ygrid, xgrid  = np.mgrid[0:w:rez, 0:h:rez]
        xcen, ycen = xgrid[arr_rez == 255].mean(), ygrid[arr_rez == 255].mean()
        return xcen, ycen
```

Here are graphed `timeit` results for these two functions over a span of `rez` values:

[image]

Its a log graph, so it really illustrates the advantage of combining the two approaches.

This is the image I used for the tests:

[image]

Comment: I would replace those `while` loops with `for`: `for x in xrange(0, width, rez):`.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - Thanks very much, I thought I was missing something!

Answer (score 2):

The centroid's coordinates are arithmetic means of coordinates of the points.
If you want the linear solution, just go pixel by pixel, and count means of each coordinates, where the pixels are white, and that's the centroid.

There is probably no way you can make it better than linear in general case, however, if your circular object is much smaller than the image, you can speed it up, by searching for it first (sampling a number of random pixels, or a grid of pixels, if you know the blob is big enough) and then using BFS or DFS to find all the white points.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
import Image, numpy as np
def getBlobCenter(imname):
        im = Image.open(imname)
        w, h = im.size
        arr = np.array(im)
        xgrid, ygrid = np.mgrid[0:w, 0:h]
        xcen, ycen = xgrid[arr == 255].mean(), ygrid[arr == 255].mean()
        return xcen, ycen
```

takes 10 ms for 640x480 picture provided by fraxel

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your blob, I would say that dramatically reducing the resolution of your image may achieve what you want.

Reduce it to a 1/10 resolution, find the one white pixel, and then you have a precise idea of where to search for the centroid.

Comment: No need to downsample the whole image, just sample it.  For example read 10 equally-spaced vertical lines, if none of those intersect the blob, take another 10, and so on.

Comment: Yes, you are right as long as the blob's shape is not too creepy. In this case, I'd still vote for downsampling